# Python 3: getting the following error while trying to scrap data from yahoo finance using pandas_datareader.DataReader() in python. how to solve it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, project, stock

PS D:\projects\Stock Prediction> python -u "d:\projects\Stock Prediction\LSTM Model.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\projects\Stock Prediction\LSTM Model.py", line 12, in <module>
df = data.DataReader(indicator_id, 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)
File "C:\Python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 370, in DataReader
return YahooDailyReader(
File "C:\Python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
File "C:\Python 3.8.0\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as data
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2013, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2022, 12, 31)
indicator_id = 'TCS.NS'

df = data.DataReader(indicator_id, 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)
df.head()
```

this is my code, can anyone solve this problem? what I am trying to get is the data of past 10 years of a company's data from yahoo finance.